# My desktop was cleaned after intellij build

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I selected desktop as project and tried to build. Are my files saved somewhere?

Comment: You can see all the files in the project in IntelliJ, if there are none then no. Theres a [local history](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html), maybe there are some files you can recover

Comment: Make sure not to set IntelliJ IDEA compiler output directory to any location that you don't want to be deleted on rebuild.

Comment: i set desktop as output directory... 
Is there any way I can recover?

Comment: No...IntelliJ assumed that it can clean things out at a folder, and it did just that.  There's probably nothing you can do to recover that data unless you have a backup or a data recovery service at hand.

Comment: This might be a valuable Question, but is unclear. Rewrite to explain exactly what happened, and what is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please [vote for the related feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-282146) to warn about such cases.

Unfortunately, there is no way to recover the removed files via IDE.

You can try third-party disk recovery tools.